# Change the height of a Google 3D-pie chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pie-chart

Is there a way to change the height of a 3D Pie Chart? We need to show users differences between a few of charts. Some must be larger in height (they must be rather like pillars then pies), some smaller. In other words, I want the pie itself tot be taller (the y-component of the pie), not the whole chart.

Here's the documentation and examples of the pie: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#3D

If it's not possible, maybe there are other good alternatives of 3D-pie charts?

I'd appreciate links to tutorials of how to draw a 3D-pie chart (using SVG or Canvas) too.

Comment: The Google Visualization API PieCharts do not allow you to customize the pie height.

Answer (score 0):

The code is right there on the page you linked!?

Here: http://jsbin.com/jibucebe/1/  3d piechart with different height..

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I want the pie itself to be taller, not the whole chart.